# How to create only internal load balancer with ingress-nginx chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

In my AWS EKS, I have installed nginx-ingress with following command:

```sh
helm upgrade --install -f controller.yaml \
    --namespace nginx-ingress \
    --create-namespace \
    --version 3.26.0 \
    nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

Where `controller.yaml` file looks like this:

```yaml
controller:
  ingressClass: nginx-internal
  service:
    internal:
      enabled: true
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I have few applications, and individual ingresses per application with different virtual hosts and I want all ingress objects point to internal load balancer,
Even if I set `ingressClass` in ingresses of applications, It seems they point to Public Load balancer:

```yaml
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-internal
```

So, is there a way to create only single internal load balancer with its ingresses pointing to that load balancer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get this working by using the following `controller.yaml`

```yaml
controller:
  ingressClassByName: true
  
  ingressClassResource:
    name: nginx-internal
    enabled: true
    default: false
    controllerValue: "k8s.io/ingress-nginx-internal"

  service:
    # Disable the external LB
    external:
      enabled: false

    # Enable the internal LB. The annotations are important here, without
    # these you will get a "classic" loadbalancer
    internal:
      enabled: true
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

Then you can use the `ingressClassName` as follows

```yaml
kind: Ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal
```

It's not necessary but I deployed this to a namespace that reflected the internal only ingress

```
helm upgrade --install \
  --create-namespace ingress-nginx-internal ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx-internal \
  -f controller.yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

Noticed in your `controller.yaml` that you enabled `internal` setup. According to [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx#additional-internal-load-balancer), this setup creates two load balancers, an external and an internal, in case you want to expose some applications to internet and others only inside your vpc in same k8s cluster.

If you want just one internal load balancer, try to setup you `controller.yaml` like this:

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true" 
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet-xxxxx,subnet-yyyyy,subnet-zzzzz"
```

It will provision just one NBL that routes the traffic internally.

Using `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets` annotation, you can choose which Availability Zones / Subnets your load balancer will routes traffic to.

If you remove `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type` annotation, a Classic Load Balancer will be provisioned instead of Network.

Comment: Following your instructions (And pretty every other instruction on the Internet) whenever I set `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme` to `internal`, it provisions an `internet-facing` NLB. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Based on @rmakoto answer, it seems some configs are missing, in order to tell AWS to create an internal NLB. I've tried with the following configs, and now it works like expected:

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: "k8s-nlb"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internal"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet-xxx,subnet-yyy,subnet-zzz"
```

Now to deploy run the following command:

```
helm upgrade --install \
  --create-namespace ingress-nginx nginx-stable/nginx-ingress \
  --namespace ingress-nginx \
  -f controller.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want classic ELBs. This worked for me.

```
  controller:
    service:
      external:
        enabled: false
      internal:
        enabled: true
        annotations:
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```